# How can I convert a .out file in exe on Debian Linux?

Tags: c++, c, exe

I perfectly know that .exe files are not executable under Linux but I need some files to be converted in .exe. Is there a way?

Comment: Nope, no way to do thar. The closest would be to keep hacking until wine is running, and hope that it works.

Comment: You need a Linux executable converted into a Windows executable (as your question currently reads) or you need to produce a Windows executable from source code (as addressed by the accepted answer)? If you are clearer with your questions -- summarizing your situation in a single sentence is usually a bad idea -- your questions are more likely to be better received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **cross-compile** your source files with special compilers : they are runnable on one platform, but produce executables for another.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Comment: @Ishimura_Projects accept the answer please if it helped you using the grey checkmark on the left of it